# Jquery Mobile theme ignoring my data-theme

Tags: jquery, mobile, theming

I have made my own data theme and I'm trying to apply it to a form elements but it's defaulting to using the a, b, c, d, e instead of mine. I've added it to every aspect to make sure I'm covering everything but I can see in the copy it's using the defaults.

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="home">
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="home">
<label for="select-choice-1"  class="select" data-theme="home">Title:</label>
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu="false"data-theme="home">
<option value="mr" data-theme="home">Mr</option>
<option value="mrs" data-theme="home">Mrs</option>
<option value="miss" data-theme="home">Miss</option>
<option value="ms" data-theme="home">Ms</option>
<option value="dr" data-theme="home">Dr</option>
</select>
</div> 
</form>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Comment: I'm a little curious about how you created the theme "home". Did you crack open the jquery.mobile.css file and duplicate a letter for one of the swatches and change the letter to home?

Comment: That's exactly what I did. It was documented on the jquery mobile site but now I can't seem to find it. The form elements are the only place I'm having issue with taking my theme.

Answer (score 0):

Swatches are limited to a unique letter [a-z], not a word. You should make your theme "h" and then use data-theme="h" or something along those lines.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/themes.html